# Replace special characters (dash)

Tags: regex, r

I was attempting to replace what I thought was a standard dash using `gsub`. The code I was testing was:

`gsub("-", "ABC", "reported – estimate")`

This does nothing, though. I copied and pasted the dash into [http://unicodelookup.com/#–/1](http://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%80%93/1) and it seems to be a en dash. That site provides the hex, dec etc codes for an en dash and I've been trying to replace the en dash but am not having luck. Suggestions?

(As a bonus, if you can tell me if there is a function to identify special characters that would be helpful).

I'm not sure if SO's code formatting will change the dash format so here is the dash I'm using (–).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the en-dash by just specifying it in the regex pattern.

```
gsub("–", "ABC", "reported – estimate")
```

You can match all hyphens, en- and em-dashes with

```
gsub("[-–—]", "ABC", "reported – estimate — more - text")
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/JXVLyK)

To check if there are non-ascii characters in a string, use

```
> s = "plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose"
> gsub("[[:ascii:]]+", "", s, perl=T)
[1] "çê"
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/aMSgcZ)

You will either get an empty result (if a string only consists of "word" characters and whitespace), or - as here - some "special" characters.

Comment: This is great. Perhaps I wasn't using the right terminology with "special characters". What I meant by this is characters that are not standard UTF-8. For example, ô -- these are the characters that I'm finding look odd when exporting using readr::write_csv(). Can the gsub you gave be altered to identify the "ô" as a "special character".

Comment: You can use it with a regex to match all ascii: `gsub("[[:ascii:]]+", "", s)`. This will remove all ascii from a string keeping all Unicode characters in the result.

Comment: You just need to use the `perl=T` with the above regex pattern since this is a PCRE construct.

Answer (score 3):

for special character replacement you can do a negative complement.

`gsub('[^\\w]*', 'ABC', 'reported - estimate', perl = True)` will replace all special characters with ABC. The [^\w] is a pattern that says anything that isn't a normal character.